# Remove keys that contains empty string

Tags: json, jolt

I receive some JSON's from REST API.

```json
[
  {
    "id": 58939956,
    "campaign_id": 1012995497,
    "status": 0,
    "start_time": "",
    "goal_type": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 58939957,
    "campaign_id": 1012995497,
    "status": 0,
    "start_time": "2023-11-01",
    "goal_type": "cpc"
  }
]
```

If property is not provided (key in JSON) API returns just empty string  . I want to filter this JSON and get rid of these keys (but only if it's empty for certain object). From input above I want to achive this output (keys naming can be different):

```json
[
  {
    "id": 58939956,
    "campaign_id": 1012995497,
    "status": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 58939957,
    "campaign_id": 1012995497,
    "status": 0,
    "start_time": "2023-11-01",
    "goal_type": "cpc"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **`""`** notation for keys to be removed within a ***shift*** transformation such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": { "@1": "[&3].&2" }, // the elements with values other than ""
          "": { "": "[&3]" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ is :

[image]